# Looking for Javascript Typed Arrays emulation library

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, typed-arrays

I'm searching for a library that allows to emulate Typed Arrays in older JS engines.

At the very least, I would like to support IE8 (because of WinXP) and Android 2.x (because of fragmentation of Android devices which wont likely to get upgraded)

Yes, performance would be an issue, but, as it said, "make it work, then make it work fast.."

Single codebase is more important to me right now.

Comment: Are normal arrays good enough for the job?

Comment: Normal arrays are not enough, I already have a lot of code which relies on typed arrays and especially views to work effectively.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for: http://www.calormen.com/polyfill/typedarray.js

It's a polyfill made by Linden Research. I found it via [this page](http://www.calormen.com/polyfill/). It's quite old, though (2010).

Comment: Smells very good. Testing right now.

Comment: OMG! Invaluable fallbacks page! This needs to be promoted more! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @wizzard0 The magic words are "polyfill" and "shim" `:)`. So, just google "typed array polyfill", or "typed array shim", and you may find more options.

Comment: Thank you again. You just saved me, like, months of work with two words :)

Comment: The official home seems to be https://bitbucket.org/lindenlab/llsd/src/7d2646cd3f9b/js/typedarray.js

Comment: it uses "throw" statement without try/catch blocks. this is not a good plugin for IE9