# Number types emulation on javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

I wonder if there is any library to emulate the native type numbers on other languages, like int and double. The library should emulate those types accurately, including overflow.

Every hint will be very appreciated.

EDIT:

I need to implement a [Linear Congruential Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). I can't switch to another RNG, it must be a LCG.

The problem is that multiplication of big numbers gives wrong results, thus messing the sequence.

Comment: I'm guessing your higher-level objective here is not: "I want `int` and `double` in JavaScript, just to have them." What is your end goal? I ask because the question seems slightly odd to me, and it'd be useful to have a little more context in order to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Typed Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_typed_arrays/ArrayBufferView#Typed_array_subclasses). (FF 4+, Chrome 7+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+)

It have the following subclasses: `Int8Array`, `Uint8Array`, `Int16Array`, `Uint16Array`,`Int32Array`, `Uint32Array`, `Float32Array`, `Float64Array`.

For older browsers you can check: [Looking for Javascript Typed Arrays emulation library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278619/looking-for-javascript-typed-arrays-emulation-library)

Hope you find this information helpful