# how to add Int32Array support to ie8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm using scrypt.js for password encryption, in IE8 (apparently IE9 also) gives:

```
Int32Array is undefined
```

I've Googled around, and this is just plain unsupported by ie8 and ie9, there should I suspect be some way to add Int32Array support to javascript in ie8 ?
Any leads appreciated.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/q/11278619

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski Ah yes your right, thankyou for pointing out!

Comment: I tested stackoverflow.com/q/11278619 with scrypt.js on a low end XP machine with ie8 and it tried to use up way to much memory (Chrome was fine with its native support), it just disk swapped forever. Perhaps someone can test Martin Wantke's answer as i've moved on from this part of my project by using server side encryption.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof(Int32Array) == "undefined")
{
    Int32Array = function(size)
    {
        if(size < 0 || Math.floor(size) != size) { throw "Invalid array length"; } 
        for(var index = 0; index < size; index++) { this[index] = 0; }
        this.length = size;
    };
    Int32Array.prototype = new Array();
}
```

Comment: Please add explanation to make your answer more useful.